# SignalR, asp.net how to set connectionId?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

i want to send a private message to user. I need to set a connectionId to such as in hidden field, i do it in this way:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $.connection.hub.id = $("[id$=hfLoggedUserId]").val();
})
```

When i run in firbug console $.connection.hub.id i get good value. In spite of this, when i send a message to client, the message doesn't reach.

I send e message from the server side using code like this:

```
public static void LogNewMessage(Bobine.Data.Message message)
    {
        var clients = GetClients();
        clients[message.ReceipientUserId.ToString()].newMessage("Serwer", Message);
    }

    private static dynamic GetClients()
    {
        return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>().Clients;
    }
```

If i change this line

```
clients[message.ReceipientUserId.ToString()].newMessage("Serwer", Message);
```

to

```
clients.newMessage("Serwer", Message);
```

then messages go to all connected clients.

How can i send message only to specific client ?

P.S I read about IConnectionIdFactory but i don't want to use my own factory to all hubs. Is any way to set connection factory only to specific hub? If i insert this line into Global.asax:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdGenerator), () => new MyOwnConnectionFactory())
```

then my factory is used with all hubs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call specific client from SignalR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872589/call-specific-client-from-signalr)

Comment: no it isn't duplicate, i know how to Call specific client from SignalR, but i can't set specific connectionId without using IConnectionIdGenerator

Comment: i also read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606569/signalr-set-clientid-manually?rq=1 but it didn't solve my problem, because i don't want to use my own factory to all hubs

Comment: You can't set the connection id on the client side, the only way is via a IConnectionIdGenerator on the server side. Please note that it is generally a better idea to keep the default GUID connection id and instead add it to a group, which is identified by e.g. the user id of your database

Comment: Thank's for reply! How many groups can i create ? Is there a limit ?

Comment: No, there's no limit as far as I know.

Comment: @akoeplinger That isn't necessarily true. I recently discovered that giving your clients the same connection id causes the browser (at least chrome) to use a single persistent connection across multiple tabs. If the IDs are different then each tab is a new persistent connection. Because a browser is limited to only 6 active connections to a domain, after about 6 tabs our website would just never finish loading. But when they all had the same ID it worked. Browser was smart enough to share the connection.